# Sectioning a tableview with dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift-dictionary

I have got a dictionary  where it stores an array meals and date uploaded by the user. Now I want to show a table view of all the meals stored and sectioned by their date.

How do I set up the numberOfSections(), titleForHeader(), numberOfRowsInSection() and cellForRowAt() methods required?

Below is what I current have and does not work

```
 var grouped = Dictionary<Date, [Meal]>()

 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return grouped.keys.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return Array(grouped)[section].key as! String
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var count = Array(grouped.keys)
    print(count)
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return Array(grouped.values)[section].count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodCell", for: indexPath)
    let meal = Array(grouped.values)[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = meal.foodname    //error here
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(meal.calories) + "kJ"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell
}
```

and my Meal object

```
class Meal: NSObject, Codable {

var id: String?
var foodname: String?
var date: Date?
}
```

Comment: Don't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231380/sectioning-a-tableview-by-dates-from-a-dictionary). In the linked question I gave you a reasonable and efficient answer. Did you try it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sectioning a tableview by dates from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231380/sectioning-a-tableview-by-dates-from-a-dictionary)

Comment: You say it doesn't work, what exactly is your problem? The code seems fine so far, although a bit convoluted.